# paddy field - is it countable or uncountable noun?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

> In some areas, **some fields could be found among the river, houses, etc.

Could I say "**some paddy fields**"?

Comment: Yes, *paddy field* is a countable noun, so yes you can say *some paddy fields.* And you can also count paddy fields and say *a paddy field*. There can many kinds of *fields* that are countable: rice field, football field, corn field, arable field, dry field.

Answer (score 4):

In this case *field* is the head of its noun phrase, and adding *paddy* as a  modifier to field does not change its status.

> In some areas, some paddy fields could be found among the river, houses, etc.

Note, however, that in English *paddy* may be used for either the crop (rice) or  the field, and in ordinary non-technical use usually means the field; we tend to speak of *(rice) paddies* rather than *paddy fields*, and *paddy fields* will sound odd to non-specialists.

The sentence has two other problems.

- The second *some* should be replaced. *Some* has two fairly distinct meanings: "neither all nor no" and "an indefinite number". Since your sentence appears to start by using *some* in the first sense "In some (but not all) areas", it is jarring to use it again so quickly in the other sense. Say *a few* or *occasional* or *frequent*, if appropriate, or if you want to leave it as indefinite as possible simply leave the determiner off: "Paddy fields could be found ..."
- It is very jarring to cast a non-collective singular like *the river* as an object of the preposition *among*. *Among* may take a singular collective (*the crowd*) as an object, but a conjoint object (*A, B and C*) is not taken as a whole: each of the conjoined entities should be a plural, capable of acting by itself as the object of *among*. Use a different preposition here: perhaps *alongside*.