# Is paddy and rice same in English?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

What do you call it in English?
[image]

How about this one?
http://netizen.or.id/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/20141105-132326_98.jpg

The Latin name of it is Oryza sativa.

Can we call both "rice"?

Comment: Rice is the edible product of the rice plant. Rice is growing in the rice paddy. Cultivation of rice is labor-intensive. The Latin name of the rice plant is *oryza sativa*.

Comment: See http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/76008/32

Answer (score 3):

No they are different. **Rice** is what you eat, **paddy** is where it grows.

Comment: Peter's answer is correct and concise. In American English, most people mistakenly refer to "rice paddies," which is redundant but understandable. +1 for an excellent answer and a good question.

Comment: @MarkH - Good point. Perhaps that's because many people are so used to  agricultural phrases where naming the crop is **not** redundant, such as _wheat field_ or _soybean field_.